# Updating Linux Mint Repositories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, repository, cinnamon

Support for Linux Mint 15 (Olivia), Cinnamon (Ubuntu based) has ended.  I do not want to upgrade to Mint 16 and have to reconfigure all my settings (which have taken me months to get everything the way I like).  However, the repositories have apparently been moved, so that it is no longer possible to install new software that is not already installed.

How to fix without upgrading the version?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've used mint, so forgive me if some of the advice is a bit unclear. It does seem strange that they would disable the repositories so soon. The first thing you can do is search for a proper backup program to save settings. If you don't intend to upgrade at all and are simply looking for specific updated programs you can search for them and make the packages yourself. There are many guides available out there for this. You can also search around for third party repositories online that are compatible (generally if its compatible with the Ubuntu or Debian base version number of mint you are good). Enable third party repositories in synaptic/software manager. Add the third party repositories you searched for and you can upgrade specific programs from a specific source. In some cases there are groups dedicated to upgrading older versions specifically with general fixes and patches. There are many options available to you, however without knowing exactly what you are trying to upgrade without upgrading the kernel I don't know if I can offer much more advice.